# Average of the Sum of X in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains values per user per month.

What I need to find is the average value for the sum of users in each month.

I can't do this:

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(TACMargin)) 
FROM report_sales_month 
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013 
GROUP BY userId
```

Which I don't think would get me what I want anyway.

If I group by user I get multiple rows (obviously) but I need have an average of these.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(sumtc)
FROM (SELECT SUM(TACMargin) as sumtc
      FROM report_sales_month
      WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013
      GROUP BY month(date)
     ) t;
```

You can also express this without the subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(TACMrgin) / count(distinct month(date))
FROM report_sales_month
WHERE year(date) = 2013;
```

Comment: Thanks, your second example works perfectly and is very easy to integrate with the way I have things set up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what result you're looking for. It may be the query that you want:

```
SELECT AVG(M.totalTACMargin)
FROM (SELECT R.userId
          ,MONTH(R.date) AS month
          ,SUM(R.TACMargin) AS totalTACMargin
      FROM report_sales_month R
      WHERE YEAR(R.date) = 2013
      GROUP BY R.userId, MONTH(R.date)) M
```

The subquery provide a list of the total `TACMargin` grouped by month and by user. Then I get the average of all these results.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you if you want average per month :

```
SELECT month(date) , AVG(Value)
FROM report_sales_month
WHERE year(date)=2013
GROUP BY month(date)
```